# Twilio hangupOnStar not working

Tags: twilio

I'm really struggling to figure out what is wrong with my script. I'm trying to setup a conference call that can be muted when the user presses *6. I have the logic working on the server, but no matter what I do in the Twiml, the hangupOnStar doesn't work.

This is the initial twiml when the user has entered the correct pin to the conference;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Dial hangupOnStar="true">
        <Conference muted="false">Conf Room 4</Conference>
    </Dial>
    <Gather action="/twilio/mute" numDigits="1" />
 </Response>
```

I have connected to the conference with 2 phones, so the conference works. But if i press * on either phone, nothing happens, both phones are still in the conference. I tried removing the gather verb and added an action to another script. But pressing star does nothing, so I'm unable to even get to the Gather verb or disconnect myself from the call.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your TwiML there looks fine so this is probably not a programming issue. I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide some example Call Sids for calls in which this didn't work. They will have more chance to trace the calls and see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, their engineering team is looking into it, the system is not processing hanguponstar properly for international calls.